# Resolve implicit region into explicit one

Tags: regions, geometry

Does Mathematica provide a way to take, for instance:

```
ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x,y}]
```

and convert it into a region defined explicitly in terms of x and y:

```
-1 <= x <= 1 && -Sqrt[1-x^2] <= y <= Sqrt[1-x^2]
```

--

I found `Resolve` but that only seems to be able to project onto a plane or line.

Comment: Does `Reduce@RegionMember[ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 1, {x, y}], {x, y}]` meet your needs?

Comment: See `CylindricalDecomposition` . The example in the doc is exactly what you ask (!)

Comment: I suspect the applications are far more general than the specific disk illustrated in the question, and thus `CylindricalDecomposition` will have very limited use.

Comment: @andre Answer?  Even the usage message of `CylindricalDecomposition` seems to describe exactly the OP's problem. "convert it into a region defined explicitly in terms of x and y:", "a decomposition of the region represented by the inequalities ineqs
into cylindrical parts whose directions correspond to the successive Subscript[x, i]."

Comment: If someone wants to study a eventual `CylindricalDecomposition` solution, and give an answer, there's no problem. I don't have time at the moment.